# Is $X(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T$ invertible if $X$ is full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix with full rank. Is $X(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T$ invertible? Note that $I$ is a $p \times p$ identity matrix.

Comment: Well what are your thoughts? For example if $n = 3, p = 2$? Or if $n = 2, p = 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider $X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \lambda = 1$, then
\begin{align*}
X(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
which is not invertible.

In fact, by the rank inequality $\textrm{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\textrm{rank}(A), \textrm{rank}(B))$, the rank of the matrix is at most $p$, which is the rank of $(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}$.